# Iteratively compute subtree sizes for all nodes?

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, tree, depth-first-search

I am trying to create an iterative version of this:

```
def computeSize(id):
   subtreeSize[id] = 1
   for child in children[id]:
      computeSize(child)
      subtreeSize[id]+=subtreeSize[child]
```

"Iterative" meaning no recursion, because in Python, if your graph is large and has lengthy linear chains anywhere, it'll give a stack recursion error.

Trying to use a stack for this instead (modeling it from the DFS algorithm) but I am having difficulty with the details:

```
def computeSubtreeSizes(self): #self.sizes[nodeID] has size of subtree
    stack = [self.rootID] #e.g. rootID = 1
    visited = set()

    while stack:
        nodeID = stack.pop()
        if nodeID not in visited:
            visited.add(nodeID)
            for nextNodeID in self.nodes[nodeID]:
                stack.append(nextNodeID)
```

For example once I begin, I pop the root ID out of the stack obviously, but after that, I've basically "lost" the ID after the child loop and have no way to assign its size later.

Do I need a second stack somehow?

Comment: What difficulty with the details are you having ? and by iterative do you mean without using recursion , by using loops?

Comment: @AnandSKumar In algorithms, "iteratively" always means without recursion by using loops.

Comment: ok was just confirming, because in python I can also deduce iteratively to mean using iterators/generator functions, which is not the same.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Not a duplicate. This is asking about *all* nodes, not just one.

Comment: Reopened, but really, the diff to the answers to your previous question is one obvious line.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat I don't understand what you are saying. Are you saying the algorithm only needs one line changed and it will work for the whole tree?

Comment: I must say that the one line to add to the answer in the previous question is non obvious to me too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested -- consider this pseudo-code for the concept of having a stack of nodes being processed, and on each node, a corresponding stack of its direct subnodes that have not yet been processed.  This means that each item on the main stack is a tuple -- the first item in the tuple is the node, and the second item is the list of unprocessed subnodes.

```
def computeSubtreeSizes(self):
    stack = [(self.rootID, [])] #e.g. rootID = 1
    visited = self.sizes = {}

    while stack:
        nodeID, subnodes = stack[-1]
        size = visited.get(nodeID)
        if size is None:
            # Haven't seen it before.  Set total to 1,
            # and set up the list of subnodes.
            visited[nodeID] = size = 1
            subnodes[:] = self.nodes[nodeID]
        if subnodes:
            # Process all the subnodes one by one
            stack.append((subnodes.pop(), []))
        else:
            # When finished, update the parent
            stack.pop()
            if stack:
                visited[stack[-1][0]] += size
```

An obvious potential performance enhancement would be to not bother adding nodes that have already been visited to the main stack.  **This is only useful if duplicate subtrees are extremely common.**  This is more code (less readable) but might look something like this:

```
def computeSubtreeSizes(self):
    stack = [(self.rootID, [])] #e.g. rootID = 1
    visited = self.sizes = {}

    while stack:
        nodeID, subnodes = stack[-1]
        size = visited.get(nodeID)
        if size is None:
            # Haven't seen it before.  Add totals of
            # all previously visited subnodes, and
            # add the others to the list of nodes to
            # be visited.
            size = 1
            for sn in self.nodes[nodeID]:
                sn_size = visited.get(sn)
                if sn_size is None:
                    subnodes.append(sn)
                else:
                    size += sn_size
            visited[nodeID] = size

        if subnodes:
            # Process all the subnodes one by one
            stack.append((subnodes.pop(), []))
        else:
            # When finished, update the parent
            stack.pop()
            if stack:
                visited[stack[-1][0]] += size
```

Edits (especially by the question author after testing) are certainly welcome.